# Highlight endif in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm creating a colorscheme for vim and want to give the `if`and `endif` distinct colors.

I followed the tutorial on
[vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-colorschemes-for-vim/) and have the following file

```
"set 256 colors for gnome-terminal
if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
    set t_Co=256
endif
set background=dark
highlight clear
if exists("syntax_on")
    syntax reset
endif
let g:colors_name = "my_color_scheme"

highlight guibg=#110117 ctermbg=233
highlight vimcommand guifg=#6792db ctermfg=68 guibg=NONE
highlight link number vimstring
highlight vimnotfunc guifg=#e6b13e ctermfg=179 guibg=NONE
```

The last lines changes the color of `if` but not of `endif`.

I used the snippet to find the name of the syntax

```
" Show syntax highlighting groups for word under cursor
nmap <C-S-P> :call <SID>SynStack()<CR>
function! <SID>SynStack()
  if !exists("*synstack")
     return
  endif
  echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

It shows `['vimIsCommand', 'vimCommand']`. Setting an fg color for any of them does not seem to change the highlighting.

How can I find the right group name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a *colorscheme* just provides a mapping of (mostly generic) highlight groups to certain colors and text attributes. A *syntax script* provides parsing rules to identify syntax elements. Those syntax groups (e.g. `vimCommand`) are then linked to the generic highlight groups (such as `Statement`).

Though a custom colorscheme could indeed provide a special color for, say, `vimCommand`, this is unusual. You can do that in your own colorscheme, but you can also perform the `:hi link ...` override in your `~/.vimrc`.

In any case, you can only assign distinct colors to **separate** syntax groups.

The [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin is similar to the snippet in your question. With it, and by looking into the syntax definition in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/vim.vim`, I see that `if` belongs to the `vimNotFunc` group (together with `elseif`, `return`, and `while`), whereas `endif` is put together with all Vimscript commands into `vimCommand`. So, any color change would also affect many other commands, which may not be what you want.

To fix that, you'd need to tweak the syntax rules itself, by defining overriding `:syntax` commands, and putting them in `~/.vim/after/syntax/vim.vim`. That's possible, but tedious (especially considering you might want to have the same for other languages, too). I'd rather reconsider whether you don't live with the predefined groupings.